# Can a host get a virus from a USB device if the guest has control of the device?

Tags: virtual-machine, virus

For example, if running Windows with a Linux guest, is it safe to stick in a USB to scan for viruses with Linux, or can it infect the host OS as well?

Comment: without specifics, the only possible answer can be yes. the host channels all the IO from the device to the guest, and the device must be visible to the host in order for it to become connected to the guest, so autoplay features triggered from the initial plugging in can execute autoplay-triggered malware on the host.

Comment: I see. Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: nah, since it isn't a universal answer. if you were running a baremetal hypervisor for instance, this risk would be mostly mitigated, but there is still the remote possibility that the malware was designed to attack ESXI or HyperV, or whatever. Thats the thing about malware, its always an unknown.

Comment: Therefore, it *is* a universal answer :) Since the possibility exists, the host isn't safe. Or was my question so obvious it doesn't deserve an answer?

Comment: no, I just don't feel like I deserve much credit for it. but you make a valid point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specifics, the only possible answer can be yes.

The host channels all the IO from the device to the guest, and the device must be visible to the host in order for it to become connected to the guest, so autoplay features triggered from the initial plugging in can execute autoplay-triggered malware on the host.

A Host OS dedicated to virtualization, rather than productivity is less of a concern, as it likely lacks features like autoplay, etc, and has a much smaller vulnerable surface area, but that isn't a panacea. Malware can do whatever it is programmed to do, and while there are mitigations, assuming it can do the worst is always the safest approach.

I should point out that of the kinds of malware out there, Viruses in particular would probably not be able to cross any particular host-to-guest boundraries, but Trojans definitely can, and a well written worm may be able to exploit both the guest and the host (as seperate infections; unless you are talking about purple-pill like kernel exploits, guest software almost never knows its virtual). Viruses themselves are largely extinct; killed off by autoupdating applications, and security enhancements to applications with network communications capability.